How to add dynamic twig on Logout Events?
A somewhat simple Symfony application is supposed to display certain twig components when the user logs out.
Following the docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/the-fast-track/en/12-event.html
I used an EventListener adding certain global variables, e.g. "some_var", to the twig Environment so the component can be conditionally rendered with an {% if some_var %} block.
However right at the end of of the example the docs mention this:

We will talk about a much better alternative performance-wise in a later step

But I am unable to find this later step...can anyone help find the doc, or does anyone know of an alternative with better performance?

If the question is finding the missing doc, then your question is off-topic here on Stack  and you probably want to raise an issue on the Symfony documentation's github - However if you clarify what's not working for you and what you are expecting then maybe people here can help you

its kind of 2 questions: "anybody know where the doc is" and "anyone know of any alternative with better performance", however I do admit that I did not clarify that. Updated the question.

Asking for better performance will only lead to opinionated answers making the question off topic as well

What is the topic in your opinion?

If you want my opinion, if it works, it works. Are you experiencing heavy delays with the approach documented?

I'm guessing this is the page you were looking for: Caching for Performance

@AdamRichard yes that tracks, thank you for sharing
